# Getting X rows before each occurance of a value in Spark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm pretty new to Spark, and I've hit a bit of a conceptual roadblock. I'm looking for general thoughts on how to to approach this problem:

I have some log data of this form -

```
+-------------+--------------------+----+----------+
|serial_number|           timestamp|code|fault_type|
+-------------+--------------------+----+----------+
|       633878|2017-12-11 01:45:...|   1|     STATE|
|       633833|2017-12-11 01:45:...|   3|     STATE|
|       633745|2017-12-11 01:45:...| 306|     STATE|
|       633747|2017-12-11 01:46:...|   1|     STATE|
|       634039|2017-12-11 01:46:...|   4|     STATE|
|       633833|2017-12-11 01:46:...|   1|     STATE|
|       637480|2017-12-11 01:46:...|   1|     STATE|
|       634029|2017-12-11 01:46:...|   3|     STATE|
|       634046|2017-12-11 01:46:...|   3|     STATE|
|       634039|2017-12-11 01:46:...|   1|     STATE|
```

Sometimes fault_type will equal QUIT, rather than STATE. I am looking for a way in Spark to select X number of records preceding the QUIT fault, and create a dataframe of these selected blocks of data, where each row could be a list of the X number of codes preceding the QUIT.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by "preceding" in terms of timestamp or serial_number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would join your data frame to itself.

On a left you select all events with fault type QUIT, on a right you select all preceding events (timestamp less than) ordering by time with limit.
Then you can do group by records on a left, and perform `collect_list` for records on a right.

Comment: Thanks, this was a perfect solution!